# Is installing an ipa remotely possible?

Tags: ios, mdm

I want to install an ipa from my machine to iPhone remotely.
For example an admin could connect to the remote (technician) phone and install the latest ipa on techinician iPhone.
Which library should I look to implement these features? I am new to MDM. Would these things possible with MDM?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done if you have an Enterprise account or if you use a library such as Fabric.io

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to be done with Apple's MDM technology.

First of all you need to set up a MDM server, e.g. Apple's OSX server (which is available through App Store / you may download via Apple developer's resources if you are an apple developer). After installing the OSX server, you may use its MDM server known as the "Profile Manager".

Then you need to register your iOS device (i.e. the technician's iPhone) to the MDM via the device's Safari by going to the MDM server's mydevice link. You may have a look at [this link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-add-devices-to-profile-manager-in-os-x-server/) for enrolment details.

You may then push app to the enrolled device through MDM. You may take a look at [this](http://help.apple.com/profilemanager/mac/5.0/#/apdB9192C34-ED00-4D42-9B64-8883E92BF604) about how to distribute app through Apple's Profile Manager.